# Delete an image from a file while also deleting the mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-delete, delete-file

I have an administration panel that has a page allowing the administrators to delete rows from the database. Each row they can delete has an associated image stored in a directory on the server. The image path is stored in the database as well.

What I need is when a user deletes a row from the table, I would like it to delete the image as well.

Here is my PHP to delete the row from the table:

```
include('includes/temp.config.php'); 


    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    {
            // get the 'id' variable from the URL
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            // delete record from database
            if ($stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM templates WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
            {
                    $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);     
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
            }
            else
            {
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }
            $link->close();

            // redirect user after delete is successful
            header("Location: edit.php");
    }
    else
    // if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
    {
            header("Location: edit.php");
    }
```

But I don't even know where to start to delete the associated image... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: putting "delete" in the manual search box or "delete a file with php" in google is where you start

Comment: um... thanks, but I wouldn't be here asking if I didn't already do that. I understand there is information out there on how to do something like this, but nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: "but nothing I've tried is working" that would be a different question and a better one, something along the lines of: this is the code I tried ... this is the out come i expected ... but this is what actully happened ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function?

Comment: I've tried a few things with the unlink funciton, but I just can't seem to get it to work properly

Answer (score 0):

I would ask the user to specify the image, select the image path from the database, delete the image from the file system with the image path I just retrieved and then delete the row from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/config.php";

if( isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT image FROM register  where id= '$id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $delete="delete  from register where id= '$id'";
    $de = mysql_query( $delete);
    unlink("upload/".$row['image']);
      if($de)
     {
        header("location:login.php");
     }
     else
    {
      echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Explain liitte bit, how this answer is useful?

Comment: I appreciate the response, however, as stated above, an explanation would be helpful. Also, you should use PDO or MySQLi for security purposes.